# В таблицу с триггером не вставлятся новые данные Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, триггер, stored-procedures

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему может получаться так, что из-за триггера данные в таблице не вставляются.

Например, у меня есть такой триггер:

```
 create or replace trigger tr_example
    after insert
    on TAB1
    for each row
    begin 
        UDL.PR_CALC(:new.DOC_ID);
    end;
```

Здесь я использую процедуру, которая вставляет данные в конечную таблицу **TAB2**.
Данные в таблицу **TAB1** вставляются посредством распарсивания файла xml через механизм на портале. Однако, если триггер включен, новые данные просто не попадают в таблицу.
Думаю, также важно отметить, что данные попадают не только в таблицу **TAB1**. С помощью механизма, они разбегаются по множеству таблиц.

К сожалению, из-за отсутствия опыта я никак не могу разобраться, почему триггер не позволяет вставлять новые данные в таблицу **TAB2**.

Если в триггер прописываю сам инсерт, проблема остаётся:

```
    create or replace trigger wdl.tr_example
    after insert
    on TAB1
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
    for each row
    declare 
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    begin 
        insert into TAB2
                          (
                              doc_id,
                              sheet_code,
                              name,
                              code,
                              value,
                              line
                          )
        select  doc_id,
                sheet_code,
                name, 
                code,  
                value,
                line
from TAB3 
left join TAB4
on 1=1
where tab3.ref_name = 'A1';
commit;
end;
```

Если же делать INSERT не черех SELECT, всё работает отлично:

```
create or replace trigger wdl.tr_example
    after insert
    on TAB1
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
    for each row
    declare 
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    begin 
        insert into TAB2
                          (
                              doc_id,
                              sheet_code,
                              name,
                              code,
                              value,
                              line
                          )
        value (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
commit;
end;
```

Сам скрипт на вставку через SELECT  я проверял. Все данные вставляются. Но именно с триггером не работает.
Плюс добавил PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION, чтобы не ругался на мутирующую таблицу.

Answer (score 2):

В приведённом коде особых проблем нет, но одно подозрение есть:

> использую процедуру, которая вставляет данные в конечную таблицу TAB2

Но в процедуру передатся только идентификатор, то есть данные надо откуда-то взять. Данные берутся из таблицы, в которую они вроде бы только что были вставлены, логично же.

Посмотрите в этом [воспроизводимом примере](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=86ab0f6a17c59bab731cdf041f01f99d), что тогда произойдёт:

```
create table tab1 (id int, doc clob)
/
create table tab2 (id int, doc clob)
/
create or replace procedure proc (id int) is
begin
    insert into tab2 values (id, (select doc from tab1 where id = proc.id)); 
    dbms_output.put_line (sql%rowcount||' row into tab2 inserted.'); 
end;
/
create or replace trigger tr_example
after insert on TAB1 for each row
begin 
    proc (:new.id);
end;
/

insert into tab1 values (1, 'document');
```

> ORA-04091: table SH.TAB1 is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

В построчном триггере нельзя обратится запросом к таблице, на которой он определён.

---

Если подозрение окажется неверно, то на основе примера выше составте свой минимальный пример с данными для локализации ошибки без догадок и шаманства.

Comment: добавил запрос триггера

Comment: @Лиля В ответе  есть предложение, создать минимальный пример  с данными на фиддле (ссылка в ответе). Поверьте, я не смотрю вам через плечо на экран вашего монитора. Я не знаю, что есть в таблицах tab3, tab4.

Comment: _Плюс добавил PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION_, а это зачем? Чтобы из маленкой проблемы сделать большую?

Comment: _добавил PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION, чтобы не ругался на мутирующую таблицу_, как понял из этой фразы, вы пытаетесь подавить мутацию таблиц и моё подозрение в ответе истинно. То есть, ответ правильный. Пожалуйста, приимите его, и задайте новый вопрос, так как то, что у вас сейчас, это уже новая ошибка. Вот накидал примерный сценарий того, [что вы пытаетесь сделать](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=beaf4214a15c4c8754641bebce4a5aee). Измените там данные, чтобы ваша проблема воспроизводилась и опубликуйте ссылку в новом вопросе.